# Using argc and argv in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, argv, argc

I have a working program but now I have to use the `int argc` and `char *argv[]` parameters to `main`. Whenever I try to do this it gives me errors that it cannot save.  Is there any way to make `argc` and `argv` work in Eclipse?

Comment: "I try to do this it gives me errors that it cannot save". Would you care to tell exactly what the errors say?

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive; `main` and `MAIN` are two distinct identifiers, for example.  I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you don't know hot to pass argument to you program, when you execute it through eclipse isn't it ?

If that is what you want, read the following.

Click on the "Project->Properties" then in "Run/Debug settings" click on the "New button". Choose C++ application. Here you can see that there are 4 tabs, and the second tab is called "arguments".
In this tab you can see a textarea. Type your application's argument there, and click "OK".
When you will execute your application thanks to the "play" button of eclipse, your program will be called with arguments.

Comment: Does Eclipse not provide a way to specify command-line arguments when you execute the program?  Setting the arguments as part of the project configuration seems rather silly.  Another option is to run the program from a command line.

Comment: I am agree with you, that is silly. Personaly, i run my programs from the command line as you said.