# Significance of argc and argv in int main( int argc, char** argv ) in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, argv, argc

In the following program for loading and displaying image in openCV

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>   
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;  
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )  
{  
    if( argc != 2)   
    { 
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand how the programmer is specifying the input image. This is because argv[1] is just an array element and I think has no relation to the image to be specified, and it hasn't been defined anywhere in the program. Can anybody clear my doubts?

One more thing: What is being checked in the "if" statement that checks if(argc !=2)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9281217/2151446

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
main( int argc, char** argv )
           |            |
           |            |
           |            +----pointer to supplied arguments
           +--no. of arguments given at command line (including executable name)
```

Example :

```
display_image image1.jpg
```

Here,

```
argc will be 2
argv[0] points to display_image
argv[1] points to image1

if(argc !=2 )
   ^^ Checks whether no. of supplied argument is not exactly two
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but when do i have to write "display_image iamge1.jpg", i mean are we going to write it in the program??

Comment: @venus When you compile & link your program , it'll generate an executable with same name as that of your `.cpp` file. Use `./display_image image1.jpg` at the terminal (on linux) or `display_image.exe image1.jpg` at command prompt (on windows). For more details google _"how to use command line arguments in c++"_

Comment: @POW Thanks for your guidance...it works...thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

The program is meant to be called from the command line with one argument which specifies the filename:

```
$ display_image filename.jpg
```

In this case the `argv[1]` will be a pointer to the string "filename.jpg".

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but what does the filename signify...is it image name? I am using Eclipse, so, can I use command line interface?..pardon me for bothering you if my question sound silly.

Comment: Yes, it's a command line program, and you run it by typing the name of the program followed by the name of the file you want to process. I don't know anything about Eclipse I'm afraid but I expect it has a way to specify command line arguments for the target program.

Answer (score 1):

When a user runs the program from a command line interface, they can specify a path to the file after typing the program name: `imdisplay image.jpg`

`argc` contains the number of total arguments, including the name of the program. Thus if the user didn't type an image name, then `argc` is 1. `argv` is an array of `char*`s of size `argc`. so `argv[0]` is the name of the program as typed by the user, and `argc[1]` is the first argument.

`if (argc != 2)` will happen if the user is using the program incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but what do you mean by program name, is it the name of .cpp file inside a project(ie in Eclipse). Where do I have to write imdisplay image.jpg???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Visual Studio**

argv[1] corresponds to **[Project Properties]**->**[Configuration Properties]**->**[Debug]**

It can set the imiage name and address